# How to join PHP with HTML forms to make a working page?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, forms

I stuck at creating a form that will work i.e. take user input and insert into DB.
I have a code, that i know works on its own. the PHP code when run bare with hard-coded values, works. FORM without PHP works.

When I put it all together, nope. I would really appreciate any input!

P.S. I know some names might be odd and it overall very simple, but I don't want to spend time on something that might not even work, and I really have to make it working, preferably yesterday.

HTML:

```
 <?php require 'insert.php';?>
<html>

   <head>
      <style>
         .error {color: #FF0000;}
      </style>
   </head>

   <body>


      <h2>Absolute classes registration</h2>

      <p><span class = "error">* required field.</span></p>

      <form method = "post" action = "<?php 
         echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Username:</td>
               <td><input type = "text" name = "username">
                  <span class = "error">* <?php echo $usernameErr;?></span>
               </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>E-mail: </td>
               <td><input type = "text" name = "email">
                  <span class = "error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
               </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
               <td>Password:</td>
               <td> <input type = "text" name = "password">
                  <span class = "error"><?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
               </td>
            </tr>

            <td>
               <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit"> 
            </td>

         </table>

      </form>


   </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
       require 'dbconn.php';
         // define variables and set to empty values
         $usernameErr = $emailErr = $passwordErr = "";
         $username = $email = $password = "";

         if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
               $usernameErr = "Name is required";
            }else {
               $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
            }

            if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
               $passwordErr = "Password required";
            }else {
               $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
            }

            if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
               $emailErr = "Email is required";
            }else {
               $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

               // check if e-mail address is well-formed
               if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                  $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
               }
            }



         }

         function test_input($data) {
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
         }  




            $sql = "INSERT INTO User_tbl (username, password, email) VALUES (:username, :password, :email)";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            //$stmt->bindParam(':token',$token,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':password',$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            //$stmt->bindParam(':fname',$user_fname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            //$stmt->bindParam(':lname',$user_lname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            //$stmt->bindParam(':telephone',$user_telephone,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);

            //$token = '436546brty546b45y'; // generate unique token
            $username = $_POST["username"];
            $password = $_POST["password"]; //encrypt password
            //$fname = $_POST['fname'];
            //$lname = $_POST['lname'];
            //$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
            $email = $_POST["email"];

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

            //header('location: welcome.php');



      ?>
```

Conn:

```
<?php
$servername = 'redacted';
$login = 'redacted';
$password = 'redacted';
$DBname = 'redacted';

// Establish database connection.
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$DBname", $login, $password);

//print error or success
if ($pdo->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed."/* . $conn->connect_error*/);
    }

if ($pdo) {
        echo "Connected successfully";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is not working? What errors do you get?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!x** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You do not need the `test_input()` function if you are using prepared statements.

Comment: Blank screen. No errors just white screen. Passwords - I know, but since I'm struggling with making it work, I have switched everything down to bare basics to first make sure it works and then add to it.